# Tableau connectivity through apache Kylin

Tags: tableau-api, cube, kylin

In Apache kylin we read the hive tables and build the cube out of it.

And tableau we connect through Apache Kylin ODBC driver, but when i connect i can see only hive tables ...internally it might be using cube but i cant see any. 
 lets say if i have build 2-3 cubes with same data set( weekly, monthly, full)..how it decides which cube to hit.  Because we dont see which cube is getting used and moreover we dont have any control to force system to use particluar cube..
  there are very less docs on Apache Kylin.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://github.com/albertoRamon/Kylin/tree/master/KylinWithTableau) contribution. Thanks!

Comment: Kylin's idea is analyst can use their original queries. Meaning you shall query against the original tables as if you are querying Hive. Kylin will determine the most suitable cube based on the query automatically.